# How to refresh a component from different component where both component views are in different pages(tabs)?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-components

I want to refresh data in a component from another component when both the component views are in different pages(tabs).

Comment: Update the data that is bind with the dom elements. Use component to component communication using events pub sub via a service. Check https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM Sharing data between components you can choose one and trigger a data change